# What is the use of multiple nodehandles

Tags: ros, nodehandle

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I didn't really get the concept of nodehandles from the ROS wiki and couldn't find any concise answer with google. I understood that a ROS node can have multiple nodehandles and they refer to the same node. In a node's main(), I first initialize the node using ros::Init() and then use a nodehandle for starting and shutting down the node. So what does the declaration of multiple nodehandles do in this case?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/218348/what-is-the-use-of-multiple-nodehandles/) by [takahashi](https://answers.ros.org/users/23199/takahashi/) on ROS Answers with karma: 185 on 2015-09-28

Post score: 4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Two reasons for having different `NodeHandle` instances in the same node are:

**1. namespace scope:** This is the most common usecase, and specifies the namespace prefix that applies to all [graph resource names](http://wiki.ros.org/Names) that hang from it. This is what @Boris refers to in his answer. For instance, the following two constructs are equivalent:

```
ros::NodeHandle("/foo").hasParam("bar");
ros::NodeHandle().hasParam("/foo/bar");
```

**2. control callback spinning:** This usecase is more advanced, or at least less common. It is possible to assign [different callback queues](http://wiki.ros.org/roscpp/Overview/Callbacks%20and%20Spinning#Advanced:_Using_Different_Callback_Queues) to different `NodeHandle` instances, so you can for instance have a node in which some callbacks are processed at high-frequency (e.g. control commands), while others are processed at a slower rate.

---

Originally posted by [Adolfo Rodriguez T](https://answers.ros.org/users/410/adolfo-rodriguez-t/) with karma: 3907 on 2015-09-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 8

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The most common use is to get access to both private and global ROS namespaces.

So a very typical thing to do would be something like this:

```
node_ = ros::NodeHandlePtr(new ros::NodeHandle);
pnode_ = ros::NodeHandlePtr(new ros::NodeHandle("~"));
```

with this approach you can publish your topics on the global namespace by using `node_->advertise<...>(...)`, while accessing parameters under private namespace with `pnode_->param(...)`.

Also note that `NodeHandlePtr` is actually a shared pointer (smart pointer), so it does internal reference counting, thus it controls object's lifetime.

---

Originally posted by [Boris](https://answers.ros.org/users/2873/boris/) with karma: 3060 on 2015-09-28

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 8

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [takahashi](https://answers.ros.org/users/23199/takahashi/) on 2015-09-29**:
Thank you for the answer and especially for the note about the shared pointer nature.

**Comment by [takahashi](https://answers.ros.org/users/23199/takahashi/) on 2015-09-29**:
Do you have an example of another possible use case?

**Comment by [Boris](https://answers.ros.org/users/2873/boris/) on 2015-09-29**:
Not really, apart from what Adolfo mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can use this  [blog](http://dougsbots.blogspot.in/2012/09/ros-launch-files-and-parameters.html) for better understanding.

---

Originally posted by [SVS](https://answers.ros.org/users/19399/svs/) with karma: 233 on 2015-09-29

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3